# How do I invite people to like my company's page?

Tags: facebook

One of my friends on Facebook did a mass invite that I am interested doing myself. I got a message in my notification section which linked his page. I could click on that link and directly "like" the page. The text in my notification's list read, "[Name of friend] has invited you to like his new page [name of page with a link]."

I would like to do this for my own business's page. I have hit "Share" which makes the site show up on my profile, but people are liking my share, which doesn't give me the result I want. I would like people to be invited to like my site directly so they can get status updates and see our pictures and promotions. I'm fairly certain that these friends are interested in such a thing, they just aren't Facebook savvy enough to know how to do that. I'm hoping the notification to directly like the page will help them understand and streamline the process so the friends who want to connect with my business can "like" the site and I can leave my other friends alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First ensure that you are using Facebook using your personal profile.  You cannot invite friends using a business account or if you are using Facebook as the Page, because business accounts and Pages do not have friends.  If you are using Facebook as the Page, switch back to using Facebook as you using the ▾ menu in the upper right corner.

Using your personal Facebook profile, which must be an admin of the page, choose **Invite Friends** from the **Build Audience ▾** menu on your page's admin panel.

[image: Build Audience Menu]

From Facebook Help:

> [**How do I invite friends to my Page?**](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=174333482624856#How-do-I-invite-friends-to-my-Page?)
>
> To invite friends to your Page:
>
> 1. Open your Page's [admin panel](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=283707085028607)
> 2. Click **Build Audience ▾**
> 3. Select **Invite Friends...**
>
> Use the dropdown menu to
>   choose a list or select **Search All Friends**. Next, scroll through your
>   friends and check the boxes next to the names of the people you want
>   to invite. You can also search for friends in the menu's search box.
>   When you're done selecting friends, be sure to click **Submit** to send
>   your friends invitations to your Page.

Comment: But when I do this, the only options that come up are Invite E-mail Contacts (like from my personal e-mail) or Create an Ad. Why don't I see an Invite Friends option?

Comment: @jmercaldo: Are you logged in to a business account?  Business accounts do not have Friends.  Use your personal account if it is an admin of the page.